# Can you set up a service to use ngResource in Angular, or does it have to be a factory?

Tags: ngresource

In almost every tutorial I've seen on using ngResource in Angular JS I see them set up the $resource as part of a factory. My question is can this also be set up as a service as well that could be injected into the controller? I just wanted to clarify that before I start writing any code on it. Thanks!